# C# - Add Custom Tag Metada on audio file

Tags: c#, audio, metadata, wav

I would like to add some custom id in metadata in audiofile (i need to know the history of the file based on this id) like Audacity do with its metadata editor.
[image: Metadata Editor]

I need to do it in C#

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: What code ? I need code. I tried taglib# and NAudio but i can't have that kind of feature.

Answer (score 0):

ATL.Net (https://github.com/Zeugma440/atldotnet) supports adding custom fields to many audio formats' metadata.

Sample code (taken from their homepage; custom field is added in the last-but-one line) :

```cs
using ATL.AudioData;

Track theTrack = new Track(audioFilePath);

// Works the same way on any supported format (MP3, FLAC, WMA, SPC...)
System.Console.WriteLine("Title : " + theTrack.Title);
System.Console.WriteLine("Duration (ms) : " + theTrack.DurationMs);

theTrack.Composer = "Oscar Wilde (アイドル)"; // Support for "exotic" charsets
theTrack.AdditionalFields["customField"] = "fancyValue"; // Support for custom fields
theTrack.Save();
```